Selenium IDE Not Executing Sequentially
I'm encountering an issue with Selenium IDE. Specifically, step 19 in my execution sequence doesn't run properly when executed as part of the full sequence. However, it works perfectly fine when run separately
Has anyone experienced a similar issue or have any suggestions on how to resolve this problem?
Thanks in advance for your help!
1.open on https://000.0000.0000/
2.setWindowSize on 1005x850
3.Trying to find id=menu1452...
4.selectFrame on index=0
5.click on xpath=//tbody[@id='listTBODY']/tr/td/div/ins
6.click on name=000021803
7.click on name=doOpenDoc
8.storeWindowHandle on root
9.selectWindow on handle=${win7085}
10.waitForElementVisible on id=ext-element-434 with value 10000
11.click on id=ext-element-434
12.click on id=ext-element-580
13.click on id=ext-element-656
14.click on id=ext-element-692
15.click on id=ext-element-436
16.pause on 3000
17.selectFrame on index=0
18.pause on 3000
19.click on css=.col:nth-child(14) .field
20.select on css=.col:nth-child(14) .field with value label=restrict
21.click on name=doSendDoc

